# Android studio want to change only last part of package name

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Want to change package name but after push refactor change package name it give me the option only to change last part(myapplication) but not full name (**com.myproject**). Dont know how to change full name of package
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on settings icon and uncheck `Compact Empty Middle Packages`

[image]

Comment: look at screenshot its already checked Compact Empty Middle Packages and im trying to rename them

Comment: you must **uncheck** it